# Update child's value

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How I can update child value (*ID*) when my code is:

```
let usersDatabaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("usersDatabase").child(userID).child("Customers")
    usersDatabaseRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let userCustomerSnap = childSnap
            for customer in userCustomerSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let customerSnap = customer
                let dict = customerSnap.value as! [String: Any]
                let id = dict["ID"]
                let employee = dict["Assigned employee"]

                let myService = ServiceModel(id: id as? String, employee: employee as? String)
                self.serviceList.append(myService)
            }
            self.tableViewService.reloadData()
```

My code works but after modifications is not good.
Below is my existed code to update value but how I say - not working now.

```
func updateService(id:String) {
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("usersDatabase").child(userID).child("Customers")
    let serviceStatus = ["ID": id
    ]
    ref.child(id).updateChildValues(serviceStatus)
}
```

Comment: Your updateService function is going to try to update the key of *your_firebase/Customer/some_id/ID: some_id* and I don't think that's the correct path as it should be *your_firebase/usersDatabase/userID/Customers/some_customer/ID:*

Comment: After edit code in line `let dict = customerSnap.value as! [String: Any]` is error: _Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1b6c455e8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1b6c46768)_

Comment: That's most likely because the value of the customerSnap is a String in your Firebase, not a key: value pair (a dictionary). You'll have to inspect your Firebase structure to see what it is as it's not included in the question.